# Реконструкция изображения из субпиксельного вращения

Tags: c, изображения, обработка-изображений, обработка-сигналов

Ищу способы сделать хайрезные картиночки на фотоматрицу с низким разрешением. Одна из идей - вращать объектив, получая субпиксельные сдвиги пикселей, которые потом склеить в большую картинку. Далее я опишу процесс симуляции этого действа.

Берем обычную картинку, это у нас будет реальная сцена:
[image: обычная картинка]

Затем вращаем и уменьшаем ее как-то так:

```
   for angle in {1..360}; do convert tree.jpg -gravity center -rotate $angle -crop 512x512+0+0 +repage -resize 32x32 low/$angle.jpg;done
```

Получаем на выходе кучу маленьких картинок:
[image: куча картинок в низком разрешении]

Примерно такой датасет я планирую получить с реальной камеры, которая вращается.

Затем я делаю апскейл картинок:

```
  for angle in {1..360}; do convert low/$angle.jpg -gravity center -rotate -$angle -crop 32x32+0+0 +repage -resize 512x512 hi/$angle.jpg;done
```

Возможно здесь уже кроется ошибка, так как при обрезке до 32 пикселей, возможно субпиксельное смещение изображения. Однако я делал похожий вариант с рендерингом векторной графики и тоже получил подобный результат.

Тем не менее, если "наивно" склеить все картинки, то получается мыло. Клей выглядит так:

naive.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WIDTH 512
#define HEIGHT 512
#define PIXELS (WIDTH * HEIGHT)
#define BYTES (WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3)

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t *sum = malloc(BYTES * 4);
    uint8_t *inbuf = malloc(BYTES);

    memset(sum, 0, BYTES * 4);

    int q, count = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        if(fread(inbuf, 1, BYTES, stdin) < 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        for(q = 0; q < BYTES; q++)
        {
            sum[q] += inbuf[q];
        }
        count++;
    }

    for(q = 0; q < BYTES; q++)
    {
        inbuf[q] = sum[q] / count;
    }

    fwrite(inbuf, 1, BYTES, stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Иными словами, простое сложение пикселей.

На выходе получаем:

[image: результат]

Что далеко от начального варианта.

Вот еще вариант, но уже с рендерингом векторной информации:

[image: Чайники]

Возможно, тут субпиксельная информация некорректна из-за алгоритма антиалиасинга

А вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для сравнения, первый кадр, просто растянутый бикубиком:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, разницы почти нету. Вопрос: как реконструировать картинку, увеличивая разрешение? Современные методы супер-резолюшена основаны на нейросетях, а мне же нужны реальная информация из соседних кадров. В какую сторону двигаться мне?

Comment: Добавьте метку [tag:c], раз он используется, так будет больше просмотров

Comment: Добавил, но язык тут непринципиален. Я просто не знал как или чем склеить картинки.

Comment: Первую бы картинку тоже с обычным растягиванием увидеть, а то не понятно насколько конечный результат от растягивания отличается.

Answer (score 2):

Ленивый метод слишком ленивый. Если вращать самостоятельно картинки из датасета, то результат будет намного лучше. Я реализовал это в маткаде и выглядит уже лучше чем, что получилось у вас
[image: Код в программе Mathcad Prime]

Идея следующая: мы знаем углы у картинок в датасете и в цикле поворачиваем картинку обратно, по нехитрой формуле высчитываем "настоящие" координаты пикселя:
*newX = xc + (x-xc) * cos + (y-yc) * sin

newY = yc + (y-yc) * cos - (x-xc) * sin*,
где sin и cos от угла изображения
Новые координаты получаются дробными, но домножив на отношение исходного размера изображения к размеру картинок в сете, мы получаем бОльшую точность целой части. И таким образом заполняем наше новое изображение. Остальные, незакрашенные пиксели можно заполнить любым удобным вам образом, я воспользовался средним значением четырех соседей.
Исходное изображение:
[image: Исходное]

Результат работы программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Датасет получен аналогичным образом, но картинки 128 на 128, всего 360 изображений. Изначальное изображение 512 на 512

Answer (score 0):

Первым делом нужно из RGB вытянуть реальные яркости.

[Formula to determine brightness of RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/596216/4827341)

```
// sRGB luminance(Y) values
const double rY = 0.212655;
const double gY = 0.715158;
const double bY = 0.072187;

// Inverse of sRGB "gamma" function. (approx 2.2)
double inv_gam_sRGB(int ic) {
    double c = ic/255.0;
    if ( c <= 0.04045 )
        return c/12.92;
    else 
        return pow(((c+0.055)/(1.055)),2.4);
}

// sRGB "gamma" function (approx 2.2)
int gam_sRGB(double v) {
    if(v<=0.0031308)
        v *= 12.92;
    else 
        v = 1.055*pow(v,1.0/2.4)-0.055;
    return int(v*255+0.5); // This is correct in C++. Other languages may not
                           // require +0.5
}

// GRAY VALUE ("brightness")
int gray(int r, int g, int b) {
    return gam_sRGB(
            rY*inv_gam_sRGB(r) +
            gY*inv_gam_sRGB(g) +
            bY*inv_gam_sRGB(b)
    );
}
```

Далее написать функцию, которая будет выдавать от каких пикселей и с какими процентами зависит конкретный пиксель при повороте на определённый градус.

Математика жёсткая. Уравнений огромное количество.

В итоге будет три (R,G,B) задачи уравнений, решив которую вы получите результат. Матрицы будут очень большими. Потом не забыть результаты яркостей перевести в RGB.